# Chinese app included in Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I was looking at the apps on my android 4.2.2 emulator (downloaded normally through the Eclipse plugin) and I saw an app that's in Chinese (or some Asian language) - the last one of the list - that apparently came with the emulator:

http://imageshack.us/a/img543/9378/androidchinese.png

http://imageshack.us/a/img132/7469/androidchinese2.png
http://imageshack.us/a/img46/3195/androidchinese3.png

Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Input method ("soft keyboard") implementation, if I had to guess.

Comment: Strange that it should have to be able to read contacts and access the network, though

Comment: Contacts is probably for word suggestions. I have no idea why it would have Internet access.

Comment: @Shdus didn't you find the informations you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

that's a pinyin input method, since chinese language has got no alphabet, a fast way to input chinese characters with a latin keyboard is using "pinyin", the official PRC standard to transliterate chinese characters into latin alphabet.

the name of the app should be "suge pinyin shurufa" where "suge" is the name. I don't know if it's a "coincidence" but, afaik, the most popular input program for chinese is called "sougou".

on google play you can find all the information about it, including permissions reason, just search Google Pinyin IME.